# Laravel validation: rule 'validate_if'

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have the following shape of data sent by client:

```
{
   categories: [{
      name: string;
      fields: [{
         type: string;
         name: string;
         rules: [{
            from?: date|number;
            to?: date|number;
            label?: string;
            value?: number;
            rate: number;
         }]
      }]
   }]
}
```

Additional constraints:

- WHEN

  `categories[x]fields[x]type` == 'numbers'

  THEN

  `categories[x]fields[x]rules.*.from` is required and have to be validated as NUMERIC

  `categories[x]fields[x]rules.*.to` is required and have to be validated as NUMERIC
- WHEN

  `categories[x]fields[x]type` == 'dates'

  THEN

  `categories[x]fields[x]rules.*.from` is required and have to be validated as DATE

  `categories[x]fields[x]rules.*.to` is required and have to be validated as DATE

I have googled in simple cases it's recommended to do something like this:

```
$rules = [ ... ];
if ($request->get('type') === 'cd') {
   $rules['records.*.memory'] = 'max:700';
} else if ($request->get('type') === 'dvd') {
   $rules['records.*.memory'] = 'max:4700';
}
```

But in my case I can have some elements in `fields` array having type == 'dates' and some 'numbers', so I cannot manage it by using if-s.

Comment: I suppose that, not even creating custom validation rules would help here. Although not optimal I would use foreach on your categories, fields and create multiple validators with ifs depending on your from,to type...

Comment: Use `required_if`, share laravel rules you applied ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood the only possible solution is to do it in two steps:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'categories' => 'required|array',
    'categories.*.name' => 'required_without:categories.*.isGeneral|string|max:255',
    'categories.*.fields' => 'required|array',
    'categories.*.fields.*.name' => 'required|string',
    'categories.*.fields.*.type' => 'required|in:numbers,dates',
    'categories.*.fields.*.rules' => 'required|array',
]);

$dateFields = [];
$numberFields = [];
foreach ($request->post('categories') as $categoryIndex => $category) {
    $dateFields[$categoryIndex] = ['fields' => []];
    $numberFields[$categoryIndex] = ['fields' => []];
    foreach ($category['fields'] as $fieldIndex => $field) {
        if ($field['type'] === 'numbers') {
            $numberFields[$categoryIndex]['fields'][$fieldIndex] = $field;
        } else if ($field['type'] === 'dates') {
            $dateFields[$categoryIndex]['fields'][$fieldIndex] = $field;
        }
    }
}


$dateFieldsValidator = $this->getValidationFactory()->make($dateFields, [
    '*.fields.*.rules.*.from' => 'required|date',
    '*.fields.*.rules.*.to' => 'required|date|gte:*.fields.*.rules.*.from',
    '*.fields.*.rules.*.rate' => 'required|numeric|between:0,100',
]);

$numberFieldsValidator = $this->getValidationFactory()->make($numberFields, [
    '*.fields.*.rules.*.from' => 'required|numeric',
    '*.fields.*.rules.*.to' => 'required|numeric|gte:*.fields.*.rules.*.from',
    '*.fields.*.rules.*.rate' => 'required|numeric|between:0,100',
]);

$errors = [];

if ($dateFieldsValidator->fails()) {
    $errors = array_merge($errors, $dateFieldsValidator->errors()->getMessages());
}

if ($numberFieldsValidator->fails()) {
    $errors = array_merge($errors, $numberFieldsValidator->errors()->getMessages());
}
```